# Passing a pointer to a 3D array with a defined size

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, 3d

I am creating a simple game in which I have a board which I am passing to many functions to change its values. Right now I am doing it like that:

```
void play(int board[2][HEIGHT][WIDTH]);
```

where HEIGHT and WIDTH are both defined using `define`.

How can (should) I simplify it? I read somewhere that it is not a good approach to simplify it like that: `void play(int*** board)`, though what I am passing will always have exactly the same size.

Comment: It's not just not a good approach, it will not work.

Comment: What you have is correct (though the `2` is meaningless). Whatever you read saying using `int**` isn't "a good idea" isn't descriptive enough. `int (*)[HEIGHT][WIDTH]` and `int***` are not compatible types, so by "not a good idea" should read "won't work at all".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In function parameters you can omit the length of the first dimension of a multidimensional array. Therefore

```
void play(int board[2][HEIGHT][WIDTH]);
```

is equivalent to

```
void play(int board[][HEIGHT][WIDTH]);
```

You should also know that compiler changes

```
void foo(int arr[]);
```

to

```
void foo(int *arr);
```

i.e. `arr` is in fact pointer to the first element of the array passed. Note that the elements of array passed is of type `int`.
Now considering your case, the elements of array passed is of type `int [HEIGHT][WIDTH]`, i.e. a 2D array. Therefore, `board` will become a pointer to 2D array of type `int [HEIGHT][WIDTH]`.

```
void play(int (*board)[HEIGHT][WIDTH]);
```

Function call would be like this

```
play(board);
```

> I read somewhere that it is not a good approach to simplify it like that: `void play(int*** board)`, though what I am passing will always have exactly the same size.

Yes. Its true. That's because `int ***` and `int (*)[HEIGHT][WIDTH]` are of different type  which means that they are not type compatible.

Answer (score 0):

You could have the board in a struct and then use an array of structs like this

```
struct Board {
    int   width;
    int   height;
    int **data;
};
```

then you can write a function to initialize it like this

```
Board *new_board(int width, int height)
 {
    struct Board *board;
    int           i;

    board = malloc(sizeof(struct Board));
    if (board == NULL)
        return NULL;
    board->data = malloc(width * sizeof(int *));
    if (board->data == NULL)
     {
        free(board);
        return NULL;
     }
    board->width = width;
    for (i = 0 ; i < width ; i++)
     {
        board->data[i] = malloc(height * sizeof(int));
        if (board->data[i] == NULL)
         {
            while (--i > 0)
                free(board->data[i]);
           free(board->data);
           free(board);

           return NULL;
         }
     }
    board->height = height;

    return board;
 }
```

you can then pass a `struct Board *pointer[2]` to the functions where you want to access the boards, and initialize the array like this<sup>1</sup>

```
struct Board *pointer[2];
int           i;

for (i = 0 ; i < sizeof(poitner) / sizeof(pointer[0]) ; ++i)
    pinter[i] = new_board(width, height);
```

don't forget that you will also need a `free_board()` function.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Assuming that you know `width` and `height`.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this be simpler? You can include other data in the `struct` too, such as the score, if you want to **undo** the last move.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define HEIGHT  8
#define WIDTH   8

typedef struct Btype {
    int board [HEIGHT][WIDTH];
    } btype;

void play(btype *current) {
}    

int main(void) {
    btype history[2] = {0};
    while (1) {
        history[0] = history[1];        // save last state
        play(&history[1]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @WhozCraig thank you, changed to passing the address, as passing the `struct` by value would not survive the function call anyway. The reason for saving a copy, is just surmising why there are two boards, and making a use for them.